# tips'n'tricks in awk

Tags: awk, idioms

I'm looking for caveats, tips'n'tricks etc. for awk.
For example:

```
awk '$9=="404"{a[$7]++}END{for(i in a)print a[i],i}' access.log|less
```

this code, will print errors aggregated by page path.

There is a trick, to sort an array by setting WHINY_USERS to any, nonzero value, to automatically use isort function on array before printing:

```
WHINY_USERS=1 awk '$9=="404"{a[$7]++}END{for(i in a)print a[i],i}' access.log|less
```

This code will return same errors but sorted by the key name (path).

I'm looking for more tricks like this one - do you know any resource which has them listed? could you share best tricks you know?
I've never found awk wiki - only same old tuts repeated over and over...

Comment: also see http://awk.info. A wide range of writing on applications of awk (but not really a list of tricks). The best tricks in awk are, as you seem to be aware, numbered fields, split(), substr(), (g|gen)sub() and associative arrays, and of course, good ol if-then-else logic. Good luck!

Comment: `WHINY_USERS` was removed in `gawk 4.0` (see [diff](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/commit/main.c?h=gawk-4.0-stable&id=6b9ed56f74baa4af529e100dff19afcd23ed7cd8)). This flag was changing the way arrays work, it cannot be done with `isort`.

Comment: In gawk 4.0, you can use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` in you `gawk` program to get the same effect as `WHINY_USERS=1`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning

Answer (score 4):

Does Awk One Liners count?

http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt

Answer (score 4):

In version 4.0 `gawk` got a debugger.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Debugger.html

```
Starting dgawk is exactly like running awk. The file(s) containing
the program and any supporting code are given on the command line
as arguments to one or more -f options. (dgawk is not designed to
debug command-line programs, only programs contained in files.) In
our case, we call dgawk like this:

     $ dgawk -f getopt.awk -f join.awk -f uniq.awk inputfile
```